# Disabling a button is causing my form to malfuntion

Tags: c#, winforms

Does disabling a button during execution of its OnClick event cause its intended action to be undone?

If so, what's a good way of disabling it after execution of the event? If not, what could adding `button.Enabled = false` be doing to cause my form to essentially "forget" what it was doing?

Edited to include code:

Basically, I have a delete button (`Button deleteButton`) that, when pressed, calls another function (`DeleteRow`) that deletes a row from a DataTable (`tbl`) bound to a ComboBox (`selector`).

```
deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DeleteRow(selector.SelectedIndex);
}

DeleteRow(index)
{
    tbl.Rows[index].Delete();

    selector.DisplayMember = "text";
    selector.ValueMember = "id";
    selector.DataSource = tbl;
    selector.SelectedIndex = 0;

    deleteButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

With the `deleteButton.Enabled = false` in the code, nothing is changed in the DataTable or the ComboBox. When that code is removed, however, everything works as intended with the exception of `deleteButton` remaining enabled.

Comment: showing some code would be a good start

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? Also, may we have some code?

Comment: Could it be the button click is causing a postback, which causes the page to be reloaded and the button to be enabled again?

Comment: The code given appears to be pseudo code as it is not valid C#.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the button and creating it again?

Comment: It's not possible. Perhaps all that code that reloads the combobox triggers some other events.

Comment: @demoncodemonkey That was my thought. I've never heard of or dealt with a postback, but the description sounds like what I'm encountering.

Comment: @Andrew Deleting and recreating had no effect.

Comment: @Davenport Now we know it's winforms not ASP.NET my comment is void. See my answer instead.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code line by line and utilizing the variable watch window?

Answer (score 2):

> Does disabling a button during execution of its OnClick event cause its intended action to be undone?

No, it doesn't. There's a little bit of a logical paradox otherwise. `button.Enabled = false;` is fine, and it's not causing your form to forget what it was doing. The problem is something else.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as usual a nice little example proves or disproves the theory.

With a new .Net4.0 Winforms Application in VS2010 C# Express, I added a combobox and a button to a form. On clicking the button, the current item is removed from the combobox and the button gets disabled. Try it out.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WF_ButtonDisabling
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SetupDataTable();
            CreateData();

            BindCombobox();
        }

        void SetupDataTable()
        {
            _dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            _dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
        }

        void CreateData()
        {
            DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow();
            dr.SetField("Name", "Fred"); dr.SetField("Age", 45);
            _dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = _dt.NewRow();
            dr.SetField("Name", "John"); dr.SetField("Age", 42);
            _dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = _dt.NewRow();
            dr.SetField("Name", "Tom"); dr.SetField("Age", 49);
            _dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        void BindCombobox()
        {
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Age";
            comboBox1.DataSource = _dt;
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DeleteRow(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
        }

        void DeleteRow(int index)
        {
            _dt.Rows[index].Delete();

            BindCombobox();

            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```